# shiny modules: Store parameters (additional argument) already when creating module-UI instead of passing it to module's server function?

Tags: r, module, shiny

I have created a module `sliderCheckbox` which bundles together a `sliderInput` and a `checkBoxInput` to disable the sliderInput - basically a possibility to state "I don't know", which is necessary for survey-like inputs. When the slider is disabled, I want it to return a default value - most often the initial value, but not necessarily.

Now my question is: **Is there any possibility to pass this default value when initialising the UI, that is with `sliderCheckboxInput()`?** As the default value is a property like minimum and maximum, that is where it logically belongs to, and it also fits better to the rest of my setup.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

sliderCheckboxInput <- function(id,description="",
                                min = 0,
                                max = 100,
                                value = 30,
                                default= NULL ##HERE I would want the default value to be set
                                cb_title = "I don't know"){
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(width=9,
           sliderInput(ns("sl"),
                       paste0(description, collapse=""),
                       min = min,
                       max = max,
                       value = value)
    ),
    column(width=2,
           checkboxInput(ns("active"),
                         cb_title, value=FALSE )
    )
  )
}

sliderCheckbox<- function(input, output, session,
                          default=NA) { #Problem: set default when initialising module

  oldvalue<- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$active, {
    if (input$active){
      oldvalue(input$sl)
      disable("sl")
      updateSliderInput(session, "sl", value=default)
    }else {
      updateSliderInput(session, "sl", value=oldvalue())
      enable("sl")
    }

    toggleState("sl", !input$active)
  })

  onclick("sl",
          if(input$active) updateCheckboxInput(session, "active", value=FALSE)
  )

  return ( reactive({
    if (input$active){
      default
    }else {
      input$sl
    }
  }))

}


ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderCheckboxInput("bins", "Number of bins:",
                          min = 1,
                          max = 50,
                          value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  bins_nr <- callModule(sliderCheckbox, "bins", default=44)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = bins_nr() + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Whenever I need to do something more complex, like passing values back and forth, I usually end up moving the whole thing to the server side and then passing the rendered input to the ui.  When you are in the server you can do all kinds of things, like what you did with the plot.  You will probably need to make renderSliderCheckbox().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the value from the ui to the server using a hidden `textInput`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

sendValueToServer <- function(id, value) {
  hidden(textInput(
    id, "If you can see this, you forgot useShinyjs()", value
  ))
}

myModuleUI <- function(id, param) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    sendValueToServer(ns("param_id"), param),
    textOutput(ns("text_out"))
  )
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  param <- isolate(input$param_id)

  output$text_out <- renderText({
    param
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    myModuleUI("id", "test")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(myModule, "id")
  }
)
```

There are probably more direct ways to do this using the JavaScript API of shiny but this is a "pure R" solution which should be enough for most usecases. Note that you can use the input value at initialization time with

```
isolate(input$text_in)
```

because the ui is always built before the server. Things get more complicated if everything is wrapped into `renderUI` but this does not seem to be the case for you.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. In my real application the next step is to wrap everything into renderUI. So I would be glad if if you can explain a little bit more your last sentence?

Comment: If `myModuleUI` is part of an `uiOutput`, `input$text_in` won't be available when the app starts up. Your server logic will have to wait until the `renderUI` components are rendered (displayed) before fetching `input$text_in`. This can be quite tricky in practice and therefore I personally try to avoid `rednerUI` at the "top level" of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late to the party, but I think a neater way to do this is to use `session$userData`.  This is available to both the main server function and the module's sewrver function.

So, in the main server, before `callModule` creates the module server:

```
session$userData[["module_id"]]$defaultValue <- myDefaultValue
```

and then at the end of module server function:

```
return ( reactive({
  if (input$active){
      session$userData[["module_id"]]$defaultValue
    } else {
      input$sl
    }
  })
)
```

That strikes me as neater, more robust and more generic than using a hidden input.